# Не правильно маршалируется структура как результат функции

Tags: c#, pinvoke, interop

Значит имеется вот такой делегат, а точнее 2:

```
[D2DMethodId(RenderTargetMethods.GetSize)]
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private delegate SizeF GetSizeDelegate(IntPtr thisPtr);

[D2DMethodId(RenderTargetMethods.GetPixelSize)]
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private delegate SizeU GetPixelSizeDelegate(IntPtr thisPtr);
```

*Не обращайте внимание на доп аттрибут, он нужен в рантайме.*

И структуры:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SizeF : ISize<float>
{
    public float Width { get; set; }
    public float Height { get; set; }

    public SizeF(float width, float height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"[SizeF: {Width}x{Height}]";
    }
}
```

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SizeU : ISize<uint>
{
    public uint Width { get; set; }
    public uint Height { get; set; }

    public SizeF(uint width, uint height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"[SizeU: {Width}x{Height}]";
    }
}
```

Но, если вызвать делегат, то происходит вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На вопрос почему `SizeU` дал верный результат отвечу, потому что там костыль вот такого вида:

```
[D2DMethodId(RenderTargetMethods.GetPixelSize)]
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private delegate IntPtr GetPixelSizeDelegate(IntPtr thisPtr);

public SizeU GetPixelSize()
{
    IntPtr resultptr = Cache<GetPixelSizeDelegate>(this);
    return new SizeU((uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(resultPtr), (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(resultPtr, sizeof(uint)));
}
```

Почему в структуру попадает мусор, и как получить нормальный результат,  не пользуясь костылем?

> **Интересный факт:**
>
> Если поставить возвращаемый результат у делегата как `SizeU *`, и
>   вернуть результат как разыменование указателя на  структуру, то результат будет
>   правильный.

Comment: А там точно stdcall?

Comment: Точнее быть не может это `COM` :)

Comment: Но для COM есть отдельные методы взаимодействия, а не импорт функций. Более того, разве импортируемая функция может быть методом com-объекта?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Я не делаю импорт, получил указатель на `ID2D1Factory`, а дальше все через виртуальные таблицы. Поэтому первым параметром всегда передается указатель на COM объект в делегат.

Comment: А как вы заполняете этот делегат? В меня как-то была проблема с unmanaged делегатами, оказалось, что в коде было неявная конвертация делегата с атрибутами в обычный делегат.